# GlassFish application reload

Tags: java, glassfish

On GlassFish 4.1 - I cannot figure out how to reload my application (ejb web service) without using the Admin Console. I want to perform a reload from the command-line or from some other java code. The reason I want to reload is because I have another function that updates a .csv file that is part of the application. So I basically want to be able to dynamically update and reload this .csv that lives inside this application.

I have already tried enabling 'reload' inside of GlassFish, and creating a .reload file in the applications root dir. I have verified that my code successfully creates the .reload file in the correct place. I have even tried touching the file manually from the command-line, and still no reload takes place.

I have even attempted using the asadmin tool from the command line to just restart the entire domain, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

To reload an application using asadmin commands do:

```
disable application-name
enable application-name
```

Those are the same commands as the reload button in the admin console button does behind the scenes.